# Is SQL Server password is also sent encrypted

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have protected a connection to a SQL Server with `Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True`
in the connection string.

In this case, when connecting, is the password from the connection string also being passed in an encrypted form to the server, i.e. not in clear text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Credentials (in the login packet) that are transmitted when a client
>   application connects to SQL Server are always encrypted. SQL Server
>   will use a certificate from a trusted certification authority if
>   available.

This is of course only true if SSL is configured.

Answer (score -1):

It is encrypted only if your SQL server is set up to use SSL:

[Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

The Encrypt=True setting I believe only marks the string as encrypted in the web.config file.